# Unable to undo, redo, and undo again in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsundomanager

In swift (4.2), I'm unable to redo then undo after an initial undo. The selector in UndoManager.registerUndo(...) is never called during the redo and subsequent undo

I've tried this in both projects and playgrounds with endless variations.

```
import Cocoa

class UndoResponder: NSObject {
    @objc func printSender(_ sender: Any) {
        print("printSender: ", sender)
    }
}

var undoResponder = UndoResponder()
var undoManager = UndoManager()
undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: undoResponder, selector:
    #selector(UndoResponder.printSender(_:)), object: "Hi!")

print("about to undo")
undoManager.undo()
print("about to redo")
undoManager.redo()
print("about to undo")
undoManager.undo()

// output:
// about to undo
// printSender:  Hi!
// about to redo
// about to undo
```

Expected output:

```
// about to undo 
// printSender:  Hi! 
// about to redo 
// printSender:  Hi! 
// about to undo 
// printSender:  Hi!
```

Comment: The undo doesn't register a redo. See [Simple Undo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/RegisteringUndo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000206-SW2)

Comment: @Willeke , "D'oh!"

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the question's comments, I didn't register a redo. So I replaced with the following:

```
import Cocoa

class Undoable {
    var undoManager = UndoManager()
    var object: Any = "None"

    @objc func setObject(_ newObject: Any) {

        let oldObject = object
        object = newObject

        undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self, selector:
            #selector(Undoable.setObject(_:)), object: oldObject)
    }

    func undo() {
        undoManager.undo()
        print("after undo: ", object)
    }

    func redo() {
        undoManager.redo()
        print("after redo: ", object)
    }
}

let undoable = Undoable()

print("Initial: ", undoable.object)
undoable.setObject(1)
print("After set: ", undoable.object)
undoable.undo()
undoable.redo()
undoable.undo()
```

Output:

```
Initial:  (None)
After set:  1
after undo:  (None)
after redo:  1
after undo:  (None)
```